# Проблема с калькулятором вообще ничего не выводит

Tags: javascript

Написал калькулятор на js, if else он вообще ничего не выводит писал в браузере так что подключать js с css не надо

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <label for="number1">Число 1</label>
    <br />
    <input name="number1" type="number" id="num1">
    <br />
    <label for="number2">Число 2</label>
    <br />
    <input name="number2" type="number" id="num2">
    </form>

    <button onclick="plus" id="plus">+</button>
    <button onclick="minus()" id="minus">-</button>
    <button onclick="delit()" id="delit">/</button>
    <button onclick="umnozh()" id="umnozh">*</button>

    <span id="res">Ответ</span>

</body>
</html>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
'use strict';

    let num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
    let num2 = document.getElementById('num2');

    const plus = (num1, num2) => {
        let plus = document.getElementById('plus');
        if(plus === true){
            let r = document.getElementById('res');
            r = num1 + num2;
            document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = r;
        }
        else{
            let txt = 'Ошибка';
            document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = txt;
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Выложите Ваш код, чтобы Вам смогли помочь. Как же мы можем догадаться, почему у Вас калькулятор ничего не выводит?

Comment: Да я поспешил и выложил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо изменить логику. 
Вы в кнопке + пытаетесь вызвать функцию. Причём не правильно. - надо ***plus();*** вместо ***plus*** 
Так же Вам необходимо избавится от лишних параметров. Типа проверки на нажатие кнопки plus (Вы и так кнопкой вызывате нужную Вам функцию). 
Ну и надо добавить сами функции. Как пример - добавил функцию сложения
Вот пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script language="javascript">
        function plus(){
            const num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            const num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
            var r = +num1 + +num2;
            document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = r;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <label for="number1">Число 1</label>
    <br />
    <input name="number1" type="number" id="num1">
    <br />
    <label for="number2">Число 2</label>
    <br />
    <input name="number2" type="number" id="num2">
    </form>

    <button onclick="plus();" id="plus">+</button>
    <button onclick="minus();" id="minus">-</button>
    <button onclick="delit();" id="delit">/</button>
    <button onclick="umnozh();" id="umnozh">*</button>

    <span id="res">Ответ</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Только нужно еще parseInt добавить, а то как строки складывает

Comment: В указаном примере унарный "+" приводит значение к числу. Так что складываться будут все таки числа а не строки